# User and his contacts belongs to and Has many Asssociation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I want to manage user and his contacts with the relation or contact type can some body suggest me the correct association of it..

I want to run query some thing like user.companions and it returns list of contact list..

If there is any gem available please guide me. Thanks

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.integer :companion_id
      t.references :user
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :contacts
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :contacts, :dependent => :destroy
        has_many :users, :through=>:contacts, :foreign_key => :companion_id
end
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :companions, :class_name=>'User', :foreign_key => :companion_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your Contact model to:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :companion, :class_name=>'User'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use query like "user.companions", then should add the following to your User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :contacts, :dependent => :destroy
        has_many :companions, :foreign_key => "companion_id", :class_name => "Contact"
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
end
```